# Overwrite c static function behind function-pointer

Tags: c, static, shared-libraries, overriding

I have a problem which I cannot get solved since several weeks.
I'm sure there is a solution and maybe one here has an idea.

There is a shared-library called *libaudio.so* which looks like this:

```
static ssize_t out_write(..)
{
    // /!\ I need to overwrite/extend this function
    return 0;
}

static int adev_open_output_stream(struct audio_stream_out **stream_out)
{
    struct stream_out *out;
    out = (struct stream_out *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct stream_out));
    if (!out)
            return -ENOMEM;

    out->stream.write = out_write;  // pointer to static function above

    *stream_out = &out->stream;
    return 0;
}

static int adev_open(hw_device_t** device)
{
    struct audio_device *adev;
    adev = calloc(1, sizeof(struct audio_device));
    if (!adev)
            return -ENOMEM;

    adev->hw_device.open_output_stream = adev_open_output_stream; // pointer to static function above

    *device = &adev->hw_device.common;    
    return 0;
}

static struct hw_module_methods_t hal_module_methods = {
    .open = adev_open, // this function can be called after obtained via dlsym() below
};

struct audio_module HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM = {
        .methods = &hal_module_methods, // this field is public available and can be called via dlsym()
};
```

My code (also a shared library named *libplugin.so*) below runs **as a plugin** under a process.

This process previously opened *libaudio.so* (above), obtained the *HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM* and called

```
HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM->methods->open(device)
```

I have no access the **device**-instance of the process so I cannot just overwrite the write-function with

```
struct audio_stream_out **stream_out
device->open_output_stream(stream_out)
stream_out.write = MY_WRITE_FUNCTION
```

But here my hope:

As I'm running under same same process which previously dlopen'd the *libaudio.so*, I can also call dlopen("libaudio.so") and will get the same reference to this library as the process before.

I can also call dlsym(HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM) and will then obtain the same public structure.
Then I could call *open* and *open_output_stream* and then **theoretically** change the pointer to the **write**-function.

But, with my beginning C-knowledge, that won't effect the instance of the process, just my own instance.

This means: The process still has the the original **write**-function behind his instance and only my instance would call **MY_WRITE_FUNCTION**.

I know no way to force the process to reload the **HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM** and recall the **HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM->methods->open(device)** - so changing this symbol wouldn't work.

I can not change the outer code, nor change libaudio.so. I have only access to my own little libplugin.so.

I would he very thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: You're looking to overwrite a function _pointer_ rather than the actual function code, right? Also, I guess the symbol you're after isn't exported from the library? How is the libaudio.so structured and built?

Comment: As I said, I'm relative new to C so don't understand all you asked. But I know, that the process which called my libplugin.so previously called **handle = dlopen('libaudio.so', RTLD_NOW); dlsym(handle, HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM)->methods->open(device);** and **device->open_output_stream(..)**.

All code but libplugin.so is out of my scope and on a running system which is not under my control.

Comment: `out->stream.write` etc. You _are_ aware that the variable `out` is uninitialized, pointing at la-la land? It is not pointed at allocated memory. Surely this can't be the real code, please post it. If this _is_ the real code, the function pointer thing is the least of your numerous, severe problems...

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done, but only if you intervene **before** the process calls `libaudio.so`.

At that time, you could get the address of `HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM` in `libaudio.so` (using `dlopen`, as you suggested), copy the `methods` pointer somewhere and replace it with a pointer to your own methods structure. The methods in that structure would simply call the original methods from the saved pointer.
In itself, this achieves nothing, but your `open` method can, after calling the real `open`, see the returned `dev` and manipulate it.

If you didn't do it in time, the process already has its `dev` pointer, and I see no way you can change it.

But I want to warn you that it all seems fragile, and depends on the details of `libaudio.so` implementation. It will very easily lead to trouble, especially if the library is changed in the future.

Comment: Yes, that WOULD work, but sadly my plugin is loaded after the libaudio.so, the order cannot be changed :) I'm hardly searching for a way to force a reload of that part..